# SQL Server 2016 Express auto-complete not working

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I wanted the auto complete feature on my SQL Server 2016 Express version. I tried all the instructions on other websites to configure the IntelliSense.

```
Tools > Options > TextEditor > Transact-SQL > IntelliSense
```

Restarted the software but still no solution. I added some info about the version at the bottom. Please help.

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                       13.0.16100.1
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                     13.0.1700.441
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                      10.0.14393.0
- Microsoft MSXML                                              3.0 5.0 6.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework                                     4.0.30319.42000
- Operating System                                             6.3.14393

Comment: Experience has shown me that IntelliSense is reliable, up to a point. After that it's just 'moody'.

Comment: Have you installed any third-party extensions like [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/)? I ask for two reasons - one, that it may have conflicted and caused SSMS to get a little funky, or two, if you haven't, then you may want to consider it as an alternative to the native intellisense.

Comment: @JoeEnos Thank you very much. This really solved my problem and works very well. It is fast and responsive. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoeEnos mentioned... and also adding that they have a nice free Express edition that works nicely with SS2016, 2017 or earlier version.

https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/download.html